# 'XCBBuildService quit unexpectedly' Xcode 9.3 (Swift 4.1)

Tags: xcode, indexing

Ever since I've updated to Xcode 9.3 (current version), I started to get this message every time I try to add a new file to the project and often it requires me to reopen workspace several times for it to actually succeed at indexing.[image: popup error message]
[image: Exception meta]
[image: Crash trace]

Any suggestions on how to get rid of this issue will be highly appreciated!

---

### Additional information

- I found out that I **now** have this same issue in Xcode 8.3, though I've been working on it for the longest time ever and didn't encounter such an error **ever** before
- If I remember correctly, the first time I got this error was when I was working with Storyboards and an .xib file.
- This error happens during indexing
- Every new file causes re-indexing and **every time** it fails with this error
- Casual re-indexing (when there are no new files) does not cause this error to appear
- Reopening does eventually help but more often than not, it requires me to reopen it several times (same with relaunching Xcode)

Comment: You should attach the crash report to your question, and most likely report the bug to Apple.

Comment: @l'L'l I've updated my question. And I did send the report to apple numerous times.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I tried all kinds of things and ultimately cleared out cached/generated Xcode user application data via:

```
rm -Rf ~/Library/*/*Xcode*
```

And life was good again. Only one project kept failing, other sample projects still built and ran fine.

Comment: this is worked but it removes all old build data from developer folder. If you want crash log from apple then not use this command. otherwise, you did not receive crash log on your  system.

Comment: For me, I only had to clear out `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and all started working for me again.

Answer (score 7):

cd into `~/Library/Developer/Xcode`

`rm -rf DerivedData`