# XCBBuildService quit unexpectedly

Tags: xcode

I keep running into this error, which occurs at random times.

My configuration:

- Xcode 13.2.1
- macOS Monterey 12.2.1
- MacBook Pro (16 pouces, 2021)
- Apple M1 Pro

Custom defaults:

```
 defaults write com.apple.dt.XCBuild EnableSwiftBuildSystemintegration 1
```

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49638864/xcbbuildservice-quit-unexpectedly-xcode-9-3-swift-4-1

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['XCBBuildService quit unexpectedly' Xcode 9.3 (Swift 4.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49638864/xcbbuildservice-quit-unexpectedly-xcode-9-3-swift-4-1)